# used query is not supported in odbc connector: Received this error while running through ADF - Database is Snowflake

Tags: snowflake-cloud-data-platform, oracle-adf

Query is insert statement  along with with as and select statement. It was running good previously but suddenly in production it errored out with this message. Couldn't find the reason behind it
There was change in connection details

```
Insert into table a
(col1,
 col2)
with abc
as( select stmt)
def
as( select stmt)
ghi
as( select stmt)

select x,y,z
 from abc
   left join def on stmt
   left join ghi on stmt
```

Comment: What changes to the connection did you make? Assuming if it worked before the change but not after then you’re now using an ODBC driver that doesn’t support your query - as the error says

Comment: Does this query work in Snowflake UI or same error? And what is the exact error message?

Comment: Found the solution but it is very strange. If anyone knows the the exact reason ,behind then please let me know.  Query has comment line --Master File, when I removed that comment line , job ran without issues.  Initially thought it was total character count in the query that is causing the issue. So I removed another comment line larger than 20 length, job failed. I reverted the changes and then removed only last letter like -- Master Fil , job completed successfully. Didn't understand why the word file in comment line is causing the error. I removed the line and moved the code to production.